# Does TimescaleDB use exactly the same JDBC drivers as Postgresql or not?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timescaledb

I haven't found the answer to this question explicitly somewhere. At least nothing, including maven repositories, hosts any different JDBC driver dependencies for TimescaleDB explicitly. Can I use available Postgresql JDBC drivers for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Timescale is just an extension, you still connect to a "regular" Postgres.

So the Postgres JDBC driver should work just fine.